# adding custom tools to a toolbar

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, toolbar

I have created 3 custom tools, using vb.net, to run in ArcGIS. They all runs fine.They are inside a same project, in three different tool classes . Now i want them all to be added in a single toolbar, so that it will be easier to access them.

To do so, i am using the basetoolbar Item, inside Extending ArcObjects

here is little bit of  whats inside the class

```
Public Sub New()

'
'TODO: Define your toolbar here by adding items
'
 AddItem("CustomTool_Openlayer")
 AddItem("CustomTool_selectfeature")
 AddItem("CustomTool_splitline")


'BeginGroup() 'Separator
'AddItem("{FBF8C3FB-0480-11D2-8D21-080009EE4E51}", 1) 'undo command
'AddItem(New Guid("FBF8C3FB-0480-11D2-8D21-080009EE4E51"), 2) 'redo command
End Sub

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Caption() As String
    Get
        'TODO: Replace bar caption
        Return "My VB.Net Toolbar"
    End Get
End Property
```

after i run the program, i get the MY VB.net Tool bar in the arcmap, but it looks something like this, and none of the tools work.

[image]
this is the small description of the tool

```
MyBase.m_category = "mytools" 'Localizable text.
        MyBase.m_caption = "Open layer And Select Feature" 'Localizable text.
        MyBase.m_message = "Open layer And Select Feature" 'Localizable text.
        MyBase.m_toolTip = "Open layer And Select Feature" 'Localizable text.
        MyBase.m_name = "CustomTool_Openlayer"
```

someone tell , what to write in the `additem()` function, i aslo tried with the GUIDs of the tools

```
Public Const ClassId As String = "4f76ddec-f1b4-472e-90e2-97257c9c23a2"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "abdd6064-2ed1-47d4-8af5-fe4836515927"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "ac56be15-367c-4082-966f-129871b28438"
```

1. should i use this basetoolbar item, or is there some other way. i just read that in basetoolbar commands are added only not tools. ?? please correct me.

Comment: Something to try: when calling AddItem, try putting the solution name before the tool module name, like this: AddItem("MySolution.CustomTool_Openlayer")

Answer (score 1):

I Guess its not possible this way.  I have successfully created the toolbar, following the steps in this link
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001ms000000

One have to use Desktop Addin Container (Template), it will be a type of XML, and by some minor modifications the toolbar will be created. The link explains it all